# Any way to disable highlighting code inside preprocessor conditionals in MSVS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

MSVS 2015 tries to be helpful and evaluate the value of preprocessor constants in conditionals, e.g. if it thinks that `FOO` is not defined, it greys out all the code inside it:

```
#ifdef FOO
... everything here is greyed out ...
#endif
```

Unfortunately, at least for the projects I'm working with, it almost always gets the value of `FOO` wrong meaning that almost the entire contents of the file is greyed out which is quite annoying as it seriously harms readability.

I don't blame the IDE for getting the value wrong, as it's defined in quite a tortuous way, but I'd really love to have a way to just disable this feature entirely and tell it not to bother with it. Would anyone know of a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015 options, set **Text Editor - C/C++ - View - Show Inactive Blocks** to **False**.